# Как правильно задать мета теги из базы данных на VueJs 3 (vue-meta)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Пытаюсь через axios постоянно стучаться в базу данных чтобы задать к примеру  страницы из базы данных:

мета теги:

```
[id] => 1
[title] => Название сайта
[key] => title
[value] => LARAVEL
```

axios запрос

```
 async getSettings() {
            this.axios.get('/api/settings', {
                    params: {
                        key: 'index_title'
                    }
                })
                .then(response => {
                    this.settings = response.data;
                })
                .catch(e => {
                    this.settings = {}
                })
        },
created () {
            this.getSettings()
        },
```

но понял что я вообще не на верном пути.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как бы вы поступили, если надо `title` и другие мета теги страницы загружать из базы данных в vue js 3 используя vue-meta

PS да знаю что данные можно кешировать, но от этого не лучше.